# AWS IAM User Permission for a specific EC2 server not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to restrict a user to Start/Stop a particular EC2 instance (TESTSYS) and for this, I created below IAM policy and assigned to a test user (TESTUSER):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:RebootInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1a:XXXXXXXXXXXX:instance/i-abcdefgh012345678",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "TESTSYS"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I login as this test user and try to start "TESTSYS" instance I get error message `You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message:`. Below is the decoded message:

```
{
   "DecodedMessage": {
      "allowed": false,
      "explicitDeny": false,
      "matchedStatements": {
         "items": []
      },
      "failures": {
         "items": []
      },
      "context": {
         "principal": {
            "id": "ABCDEFGHIJK0123456789",
            "name": "testuser",
            "arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/testuser"
         },
         "action": "ec2:StopInstances",
         "resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:instance/i-abcdefgh012345678",
         "conditions": {
            "items": [
               {
                  "key": "ec2:Tenancy",
                  "values": {
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "value": "default"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "ec2:PlacementGroup",
                  "values": {
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "value": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:placement-group/App Servers"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "XXXXXXXXXXXX:Name",
                  "values": {
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "value": "TESTSYS"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "ec2:ResourceTag/System",
                  "values": {
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "value": "TESTSYS"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "XXXXXXXXXXXX:System",
                  "values": {
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "value": "TESTSYS"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "ec2:AvailabilityZone",
                  "values": {
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "value": "us-east-1a"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "ec2:Region",
                  "values": {
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "value": "us-east-1"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "ec2:ResourceTag/Name",
                  "values": {
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "value": "TESTSYS"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "ec2:ebsOptimized",
                  "values": {
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "value": "true"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "ec2:InstanceType",
                  "values": {
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "value": "c4.large"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "ec2:RootDeviceType",
                  "values": {
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "value": "ebs"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "ec2:InstanceProfile",
                  "values": {
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "value": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:instance-profile/EC2_TESTSYS"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When I try to simulate this policy for this same test user for `StartInstance` & `StopInstance` then I do see that permission is ALLOWED.

Can you please let me know what am I missing?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying an availability zone instead of a region. Try with `us-east-1`

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:instance/i-abcdefgh012345678",
```